# Where does oracle store undo data? In memory or in hard disk

Tags: sql, oracle, database-administration, rollback

I know about undo tablespace which is permanent. Does that mean oracle stores undo data in hard disk?

Answer (score 1):

data files are stored on disk [Source](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/physical.htm#CNCPT88986)

> A data file is a physical file on disk that was created by Oracle
> Database and contains data structures such as tables and indexes. A
> temp file is a data file that belongs to a temporary tablespace. The
> data is written to these files in an Oracle proprietary format that
> cannot be read by other programs.

And tablespaces are stored in data files [Source](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/physical.htm)

> Oracle stores data logically in tablespaces and physically in
> datafiles associated with the corresponding tablespace.

This means undo tablespace is stored on disk.